# Skip elements within a container when querying DOM

Tags: dom, jquery-selectors, selectors-api

When using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) or any DOM query method, I want to skip elements within a given sub-container from querying.

**Example:**

```
<div id="container-one">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="first">
      <input type="text" name="second">

      <!-- skip below -->
      <div id="container-two">
        <input type="text" name="third">
        <input type="text" name="fourth">       
      </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Suppose in the above case, if you are querying from `#container-one` element you want to skip elements within `#container-two`. So the query on `#container-one` should only return **`[first, second]`** elements and skip others (third, fourth).

Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.container-one')[0].querySelectorAll(':scope > input')
```

Update(You can't use querySelectorAll for this then):

```
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
input_two = document.getElementById('container-two').getElementsByTagName('input');

var input_cont_two_name_array = [];
for(j=0;j<input_two.length;j++){
    input_cont_two_name_array.push(input_two[j].name);
}

for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    input_name_id = inputs[i].name;
    if(input_cont_two_name_array.indexOf(input_name_id) == -1){
      //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Input elements can be anywhere in the hierarchy, not just direct child. so `':scope > input'` wont work here.

Comment: As per the information provided i made it for children. If you can you give me an example we can see what can be done.

Comment: Even if it is not the direct child it will give you the input elements ... working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bjn5cafv/ you can to check the console for log

Comment: I've updated the html in my question for which the solution provided by you doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, but the updated solution is not a generic one.

Comment: I have updated the code this should work for any format